# UISearchbar inside uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone

Looks like dumb question, but...:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
self.bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:bar contentsController:self];
mySearchDisplayController.delegate = self;
mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.bar];
```

All behavior is working fine while i don't press a cancel or hided tableview. 
After that search bar is closed and i see a clear navigation bar, without search bar.
I has change to viewDidload, but nothing changed.

Before start printing:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior you're seeing?  `viewWillAppear` is not really the place for this sort of code.  `viewDidLoad` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add searchbar as titleView for navigationBar. It may work.

Refer to this site:

http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/custom-tableview.html

It may helps you

Comment: it's working, [[self.navigationController.navigationBar topItem] setTitleView:self.bar]; but when i try to write something in search bar, search bar is going up and close, like searchcontroller think that searchbar placed in table, not in navbar.

Comment: can you place your code with a snapshot of searchbar(search bar is going up and close).I can see what's going wrong..

Comment: tnx, please see here, code nothing to add there just clear delegate functions;